# MYSQL Double Nest SELECT

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a 'double' nested SELECT statement. The deeper statement pulls the values I need for the per month total I am trying to insert into an existing row. However each "Segment' has differing percentages so it results in multiple rows. To get around this I have an outer select that then does a SUM the result.

More problem is I am unable to match the result to the month as the when I try to link to the columns name 'Enrol_month_short' I get the following message.

"Unknown column 'Enrol_month_short' in 'where clause'"

```
SELECT Date_format(tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date, '%b %y')AS 
       Enrol_month_short, Sum(tbl_revenue.rev_value) AS 
       Enrol_Cum_Rev, (SELECT Sum(tbl_revenue.rev_value) 
       FROM tbl_client_details 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN gridlock.tbl_revenue 
       ON tbl_client_details.cd_zbi_no = tbl_revenue.rev_zbi_no 
       AND tbl_client_details.cd_ucn = tbl_revenue.rev_ucn 
       WHERE ( Date_format(tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date, '%b %y') = 
       enrol_month_short ) 
       AND ( Date_format(rev_month, '%b %y') = enrol_month_short ) 
       GROUP  BY Date_format(tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date, '%b %y')) AS 
       New_client_rev, 
       (SELECT Count(tbl_client_details.cd_id) 
       FROM   tbl_client_details 
       WHERE  ( tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date >= '2012-04-01' 
                AND tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date <= '2012-07-31' ) 
                AND Date_format(tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date, '%b %y') = 
                enrol_month_short 
       GROUP  BY Date_format(tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date, '%b %y')) AS 
       Actual_Enrols, 
       (SELECT ( ( Sum(tbl_revenue.rev_value) * 
               ( tbl_segment.seg_growth_2012 / 100 ) ) / 12 ) AS YEAR_NEW_BUS_BUDGET 
       FROM tbl_client_details 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_revenue 
       ON tbl_client_details.cd_zbi_no = tbl_revenue.rev_zbi_no 
       AND tbl_client_details.cd_ucn = tbl_revenue.rev_ucn 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_segment 
       ON tbl_client_details.cd_segment = tbl_segment.seg_name 
       WHERE ( rev_month >= '2012-04-01' AND rev_month <= '2012-07-31' ) 
       GROUP  BY enrol_month_short)                                      AS 
       YEAR_NEW_BUS_BUDGET 
       FROM tbl_client_details 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN gridlock.tbl_revenue 
       ON tbl_client_details.cd_zbi_no = tbl_revenue.rev_zbi_no 
       AND tbl_client_details.cd_ucn = tbl_revenue.rev_ucn 
       WHERE ( tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date >= '2012-04-01' 
       AND tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date <= '2012-07-31' ) 
       AND ( rev_month >= '2012-04-01' 
       AND rev_month <= '2012-07-31' 
       OR rev_month = NULL ) 
       GROUP BY enrol_month_short 
       ORDER BY tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date;
```

Comment: hope you don't have the query that way in your code. Please paste the nicely formatted query

Comment: Which table does enrol_month_short come from?

Comment: Doing a `DATE_FORMAT` call in your query and using it for comparisons is going to be brutally slow. You really should be storing a version of the date in the format required, then indexing on that for join purposes.

Comment: @RenePot I think my attempt to 'nicely format' messed it up. I will retry

Comment: @BugFinder enrol_month_short is the alias for tbl_client_details.cd_enrol_date